# Neyman-Pearson’s Lemma a to define the rejection region of the type nx > κ Bernoulli

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, inference, neyman-pearson-lemma

I'm working through the following question:
[image]

I understand that the formula is:
Likelihood(Theta_0) / Likelihood(Theta_A)
As its bernoulli, I think it shoudl work out as below but I am at a loss on how to make it neater and put it in terms of k. Can anyone offer any advice?

[image]

Comment: Please try to use [MathJaX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset equations instead of uploading pictures, it makes the post easier to read.

Comment: ... especially for people using screen-readers - see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/17230 & https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6266/17230